# How to optimize slow MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following MySQL query and it's taking long time to execute:

```
SELECT `market`.`name` AS `Markets`, count(*) * `clicks`.`cost` AS `Rev`
FROM `clicks`
INNER JOIN markets ON `clicks`.`market_id`= `markets`.`id`
WHERE clicks.created_date = `date1`
GROUP BY `markets`.`id`
ORDER BY `Rev` DESC
```

Initially it was extremely slow, but later I removed redundant date function. Still it's taking long time to execute. Is there any solution to it?

Explanation of Query:
I am selecting names of markets from one table and number of rows multiply by cost from another table.
ID of the markets is defined in first table 'clicks' and I am getting the names of the markets from 'markets' table. and further I am grouping markets by their ID and ordering via Rev in descending

Comment: Did you try `explain ` for your query

Comment: `count(*)*cost` What it is ?

Comment: unfortunately You'll not gain best results. it seems to me that it's very big table (more than million records per day) You've to partition table by `created_date` field. otherwise db engine have to scan whole table or do very expensive indexing operation that is not good.

Comment: Create a mysql view then query data from view.

Comment: @SumeshTG count of rows multiply by a variable cost

Comment: @SumeshTG view is just another query that being executed every-time when You select from it

Comment: @num8er The size of table is 3GB

Comment: @Shyamala I have explained it now

Comment: Which table does created_date belong to? And is it a datetime or a string?

Comment: @MariumMalik it is already big and will grow everyday. So just create same table with different name and partition by `created_date` field. Then move data from one to another.

Comment: @SalmanA clicks

Comment: @MariumMalik explain refer to [this sql instruction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html), not to a verbal explanation :-)

Comment: @LelioFaieta Oh thanks! I wasn't aware about this

Comment: Just create an index on `clicks (created_date, cost)` and see if there is improvement. I assume date1 is a date literal and created_date is datetime column.

Comment: @SalmanA it will work for first few days, but after it will cost with higher cpu loads and slow inserts, since it's time-series-data.

Comment: @MariumMalik which table does cost belong to? click or market?

Comment: @SalmanA clicks

Answer (score 2):

Your query is abusing the MySQL *partial group by* feature. You're grouping by market but have a stray column `clicks.cost` that is not contained inside an aggregate. You will get incorrect results no matter how fast your query is.

You could revise your query as follows:

```
SELECT market.name AS Markets, subqry.Rev FROM (
    SELECT market_id, SUM(cost) AS Rev
    FROM clicks
    WHERE created_date = 'some date'
    GROUP BY market_id
) AS subqry
INNER JOIN markets ON subqry.market_id = markets.id
ORDER BY Rev DESC
```

Once you've made sure that the results are correct, create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_clicks ON clicks (created_date, market_id, cost)
```

Comment: Is count(*) * `clicks`.`cost` considered in this query?

Comment: Yes, how would you describe `count(*) * clicks.cost`? If there are two clicks with cost of 100 and 200, what is the expected result? `2 * 100` or `2 * 200`? I believe it should be `SUM(100, 200) = 300`.

Comment: count(*) is counting the number of rows and cost is a pre-defined value in database. Number of rows for 1 market * cost

Comment: cost is a column that has values stored in the column while count(*) sums the number of rows and later multiplies the value of cost

Comment: So, both the queries are returning same result. (So my results weren't incorrect I guess)  Can you please explain the index part a little?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean about SUM(cost). Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181466/discussion-between-salman-a-and-marium-malik).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT m.name AS Markets, SUM(c.cost) AS `Rev`
FROM clicks c INNER JOIN
     markets m
     ON c.market_id = m.id
WHERE c.created_date = ?
GROUP BY m.name
ORDER BY Rev DESC;
```

This does not help performance.  However, an index on `clicks(created_date, market_id, cost)` might get you the performance you want.

If that doesn't work, then try this:

```
SELECT m.name AS Markets,
       (SELECT SUM(c.cost)
        FROM clicks c
        WHERE c.market_id = m.id AND c.created_date = ?
       ) AS `Rev`
FROM markets m
ORDER BY Rev DESC;
```

This removes the outer `GROUP BY`, which can be a big performance gain.  For this, the index should be slightly different, `clicks(market_id, created_date, cost)`.

Comment: I get performance gain from your second query. Will be trying the index part. Thanks!

Comment: Few milli seconds

Answer (score -1):

I've to write alternative correct way of doing such logic systems where we have big amount of data every-day and we have to make summary reports without having performance issues in future.

Unfortunately it's time-series-data.

It will grow and will cost You performance loss.

For **short run** adding **indexes** may **solve** Your issue.

But in **long run** where many markets will appear, clicks will be **~1million per day** the "index workaround" is **not good** solution.

A) If You do index date field You'll get to slow inserts. Cause it will do index update procedures in background every time.

B) If You partition table, it will be hard to manage after some period, since it's not good to have hundreds of partitions and some day business will come with very "uncomfortable" task for current data structure which will result re-thinking table schemas.

Solution is to re-think Your logic:

1. Use Kafka and insert Your click data to it.
2. Insert data to `clicks` table (table should not have indexes to make inserts fast).
3. Make a worker that will get that click data from Kafka, do math, and create summary by markets for day, week, month, year and etc. By creating tables: `clicks_by_markets`, `clicks_by_markets_yearly`, `clicks_by_markets_weekly`, `clicks_by_markets_daily`

Another solution (without Kafka):

1. Have table `clicks_raw` to put request data without processing.
2. Create script that will scheduled every 10 minute and process `clicks_raw` table and populate tables like: `clicks_by_markets`, `clicks_by_markets_yearly`, `clicks_by_markets_weekly`, `clicks_by_markets_daily`

Comment: Nothing against this solution, but given the sizes of these tables, do you really thing adding extra overhead with Kafka makes sense ? I have seen way more, really way more data been handled pretty effortlessly by RDBMS.

Comment: @Biswanath Kafka is just an example. Idea is to pass data processing to independent process. About RDMS way: for now it's small. You cannot predict what can happen in future and what Op's managers will require. I've also seen more data handled pretty effortlessly (: but it was with replication, with manual data partitioning techniques and  with different data structure.

Comment: Yes, generally I think this looks more like business report generated for daily. For me I follow cross the bridge when it comes.

Comment: @Biswanath I've used ClickHouse in one of previous projects. In another I've made with Kafka. In third one I had worker that takes data that has id greater than last id and process report generation. There are ton's of ways. But adding index to date field will not make good result in long run.